# How can I get bloggers to use my widget?

Tags: blog, widgets

I have developed a widget that shows a story of a hike or an outdoor outing on a google map.  Here is an example:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?type=hike&hike_id=108&width=500&height=500

What I am wondering is - other than asking people one by one, how do I get outdoor bloggers to use my widget on their sites?

I made a page to create the widget here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trip_story.php

But it all seems clunky so far.  Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to include screenshots of your widget on the site you created for it.

Also, in the upper corner of the map (within actual map) you could include the words
"This map was generated using Come Hike" and the come hike part could be a link to your site... just an idea.

Comment: Good idea about generating the text on the map.  Do you know if that is possible to do on google maps?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding your widget to [google gadgets](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open): webmasters often look there for widgets to add to their site.

Answer (score 3):

Webmasters will only add content to their website if it adds value to their users (whether it is real or just perceived is irrelevant). Your job is to explain to other website how this widget will benefit them. What will they gain by putting this widget in their blog? How should they expect their users to react? How will their users see this valuable content? If possible, show examples.